# Find username within specific column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get this PHP working where it returns true or false if the username exists in the username column on the database:

```
$data = array($_POST["username"]);


$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Example;charset=utf8', 'Example', 'Example');

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT FROM Members (username) WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute($data);

 if(mysql_num_rows($stmt)>=1)
   {
    echo"true";
   }
 else
    {
    echo "false";
    }
```

Comment: if you have phpmyadmin or something similar, you can test your queries there in the SQL tab, start with "SELECT * FROM Members" for example

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FROM
```

Does not select anything.

You need to specify what you need to select or just * to select all

```
SELECT `username` FROM
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM
```

Comment: I think you are looking for http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php instead of num_rows()

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Members WHERE username=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement

```
SELECT * FROM Members WHERE username
```

or

```
SELECT username FROM Members WHERE username
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch a `boolean` result, from the sql query itself, with minor modification.

```
SELECT
  count(username) > 0 as user_exists
FROM Members
WHERE username=?
```

In PHP script just read the result that has either a `true` (`1`) or `false` (`0`) as value.